# Non-scrollable view above WKInterfaceTable

Tags: watchkit, wkinterfacetable

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a view above a `WKInterfaceTable` that doesn't scroll? I am needing to have some information stay at the top as the user scrolls, but no matter what I try the group/view scrolls out of view.

[image]